# Is there an SVG to VML conversion tool? Offline or Online. (Not on the fly)

Tags: svg, vml

I have been hunting high and low for a tool to convert an SVG file into VML which is readable by internet explorer.

I have found several 'on the fly' solutions but these are unnecessary as we only wish to use vector graphics on a few simple, non changing, but scaleable drawings.

Is there any tool out there, offline or online that will accept an SVG file and output VML code?

Kind regards.

Comment: Even if you use vector graphics just in a few cases, be aware that VML isn't a standard nor will it display in any software beside a few Microsoft products (and as of IE 10 they won't support VML any longer). In other words: VML is dead – so why the heck store any data in a format no one could open three years later?

Comment: @feeela - I actually had this problem when I needed to display an interactive handwriting assistant doohickey I'd written (originally in SVG) in IE7. I work in a school system that cannot afford to update its computers, and because of the IT policy, we weren't allowed to install another browser... *[sigh]* public education = government = red tape. So anyway it was either do it in VML or don't do it at all. I agree VML should die, but it can still be useful sometimes.

Comment: @feeela, we use SVG for all modern browsers but the intention is to fallback to VML for IE < 9.  Raphael.js is fantastic for normalising these crossbrowser issues but since it is for only several (non changing) images, the overhead of Raphael itself would be a severe waste.

Comment: @gordyr Well, Raphaël wasn't designed to convert SVG to VML but rather create SVG (or VML) through JavaScript. But now I understood your needs…

Comment: @David John Welsh I never said that VML should die – I said it is already dead ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used it, but my understanding is that this can take an SVG file and output VML (or vice versa).

http://vectorconverter.sourceforge.net/

Looking at the documentation, it seems you just need to install it on your server and upload your SVG file. There is a command-line tool you can use to specify an output file. You can then download that newly-created VML file (and tweak a little by hand it if it's not survived the conversion process perfectly).

Comment: Hmm... I just tried to install it on my localhost and I got a PHP error while converting. I think it was written for PHP4... I'll keep looking at it though. Might come in handy for me, too.

Comment: Yep i'm having troubles too....  I may have to just use svg2web to support old IE.  Again seems a waste for just a few images, but at least I can load it conditionally with Modernizr.  Such a shame that there doesn't appear to be a simple offline method. :(

Comment: oh wait, it works on a live server. I needed to download the original version, and then download the 1.2 version and overwrite the original's files. check it out: http://www.altastic.com/~vector/

Comment: You sir... are a god... :-)  Works perfectly!  I truly can't thank you enough!

Comment: well... a hundred million dollars would be, if not thanks enough, then at least a nice gesture ;-)

Comment: Haha, i'll come back when I sell my company in a year or two then. :-)